# WebElement getText() doesn't work on Winium-Desktop

Tags: java, selenium, ui-automation

I'm trying to execute `getText()` on a `WebElement` instance but for some reason it doesn't work: `pcresultsList.get(0).getText()`
Maybe `Winium` doesn't support this method?

My code is:

```
public void monitorBasic() throws InterruptedException {
    monitorFrame = driver.findElement(By.name("BEAM Monitor"));
    WebElement resultsFrame = monitorFrame.findElement(By.id("ReportListBox"));
    List<WebElement> pcresultsList = resultsFrame.findElements(By.className("TextBlock"));
    System.out.println(pcresultsList.get(0).getText());
}
```

sorry for not posting the error I'm getting - the site tells me that my code is not indent and when i'm trying to present it as code the site tells i have too much code. :)

Comment: You can post the error with `>` before your error text. That might help you get around the too much code thing. Or you can just post the first few lines of the error as those are usually the relevant parts.

Comment: what is `pcresultsList.size()` value?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using:

```
System.out.println(pcresultsList.get(0).getAttribute("Value"));
```

Also try to get other properties of the element to confirm you can get info.

The code below works for me:

```
element = Window.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@ControlType,'ControlType.DataItem') and contains(@Name,'G15')]"));
    System.out.println("Cell text: " + element.getText()); //writes Shipments
```

Let us know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you are trying to get some text from an element which is inside a frame. In that case you need to switch to the frame first then acquire the text of any of the element within the frame.

You need to do:

1. Apply ImplicitlyWait for 2/3 seconds.
2. `driver.switchTo().frame("BEAM Monitor");` // assuming that's the frame name.
3. Then click on a element inside the frame :
   `driver.findElement(By.id("ReportListBox")).click();`
4. Create a list to get all the elements in a list:

   ```
   List<WebElement> pcresultsList = driver.findElements(By.className("TextBlock"));
   ```
5. Create a for loop to iterate through the elements to get the text:

```java
for(WebElement pcresult : pcresultsList)
{
    System.out.println(pcresult.getText());
}
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that with Winium, you need to get the `Name` attribute because `getText()` does not work correctly.